# Caracteres iguales Java

Tags: java

en java quiero mostrar 4 caracteres lo cual lo hago con un for,  y los muestro por pantalla, pero luego lo que quiero es saber si esos numeros son iguales, si lo son imprimir por pantalla un "funcion", y si no funciona imprimir "no funciona", pero no se como se hace para igualar caracteres, aqui mi programa, me da error cuando digo que caracter==caracter, muchas gracias

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
     Scanner escaneo = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Introduzca un carácter: ");
        char caracter;
        for(int i=0; i<4;i++) {
            caracter = escaneo.next().charAt(0);
            System.out.println(caracter);
        }
        if(caracter==caracter) {
            System.out.println("funciona");
        }else {
            System.out.println("no funciona ");
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: El problema es que no estás almacenando los valores en ningún lado. Ten en cuenta que a cada vuelta de bucle la variable `caracter` se reescribe con un nuevo valor. Para almacenarlos puedes usar un array.

Comment: Por otro lado el error que te marca es porque no has inicializado la variable `caracter`. Para solucionar ese error iníciala con cualquier valor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que tendrías que hacer el tipo de variable `caracter` a tipo `array`:

Esto:

```
char caracter;
```

por esto:

```
char caracter = new char[4];
```

De esta forma podremos guarda todos los caracteres que introduzcamos en una misma variable. Como tu lo tienes hecho hasta ahora, el siguiente carácter que introduzcas remplaza al anterior, como te han dicho en los comentarios.

Nos crearemos otro array donde guardaremos todos los elementos de nuestro array para despues comprobrar que todos los elementos son iguales.

```
char comprobar[] = new char[caracter.length];
```

La manera de rellenar dicho array es utilizando tu bucle `for` donde insertas los caracteres, tal que así:

```
System.out.println("Introduzca un carácter: ");
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    caracter[i] = escaneo.next().charAt(0);
    comprobar[i] = caracter[i];//aqui
}
```

Ahora creamos una variable `boolean` para determinar si todos los caracteres son iguales:

```
boolean check = false;
```

Recorremos los dos array en un bucle anidados y comprobamos posisicion por posicion si son iguales. Si son iguales pondremos la variable `check` a `true`, si no la pondremos a `false` y saldremos del bucle con `break`, porque habremos determinado que no se cumple que los caracteres sean iguales.

```
for(int i = 0; i < caracter.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < comprobar.length; j++) {
        if(caracter[i] == comprobar[j]) {
            check = true;
        }else {
            check = false;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Por ultimo, mostramos un mensaje, dependiendo del valor de la variable `check`:

```
if (check) {
    System.out.println("funciona");
} else {
    System.out.println("no funciona ");
}
```

**Ejemplo completo:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner escaneo = new Scanner(System.in);
    char caracter[] = new char[4];
    char comprobar[] = new char[caracter.length];
    boolean check = false;

    System.out.println("Introduzca un carácter: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        caracter[i] = escaneo.next().charAt(0);
        comprobar[i] = caracter[i];
    }
    
    for(int i = 0; i < caracter.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < comprobar.length; j++) {
            if(caracter[i] == comprobar[j]) {
                check = true;
            }else {
                check = false;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    

    if (check) {
        System.out.println("funciona");
    } else {
        System.out.println("no funciona ");
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Introduzca un carácter: 
b
b
b
b
funciona

Introduzca un carácter: 
a
a
b
b
no funciona
```